# Creating a button click counter in php that links to another page

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to develop a button click counter that updates the number of clicks and also opens up a new page. I have been able to successfully get the script working on the button click counter, but my issue is that when I include an anchor tag either at the form action **or** on the button, the click counter stops working.

Here is the php script:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['button1']) ) { 
    incrementClickCount();
}

function getClickCount()
{
    return (int)file_get_contents("counter.txt");
}

function incrementClickCount()
{
    $counter = getClickCount() + 1;
    file_put_contents("counter.txt", $counter);
}
?>
```

Here is the html:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST"/>
<a href="#"><input type="button" name="button1" Value="Submit"/></a>
</form>

<div>Submitted Files: <?php echo getClickCount(); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `a` would be -

```
<form method="POST"/>
<input type="button" name="button1" Value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Simply use `header` to redirect after writing.

```
if( isset($_POST['button1']) ) { 
    incrementClickCount();
    header('location:path-to-page');
    exit;
}
```